# Show my own Ads or custom ads in my game using unity ads or admob or anything else

Tags: unity-game-engine

Simple query, I developed a game in unity, and successfully setup unity rewarded video ads. This brings up videos ads of other games and such. What I'd like to be able to do instead is setup an ads placement, whether video, interstitial or banner ads in my game and then have a remote dashboard where I can choose which ads show up on the ads spaces in the game and not just some random ads. What approach would be used to implement this please?

Comment: Top AD providers do not support such an option. I am wondering why do you want such a thing? these companies are using solid data to pick the right add?

Comment: The owners of the game wants to show ads from their company in the game. It really doesn't have to admob or unity ads. Just the best way to display personal ads in your own game

Comment: Oh, sure I get it now. I suggest you just to put a few pre-made banners and show them instead. Even more, you can put some 3-10 sec .mp4 and use it as a fullscreen ad. Make sure you test these on a variety of resolutions tho :)

Comment: Glad you understand now but is there a way to control what shows up without having to push a new release bundle to the appstore? It should like probably fetch the video or banner gifs remotely

Comment: I think I was answering my own question while making that comment, setup blank spaces in and around the game and then when it's time for ads, set the screens active and then make network requests for the videos or gifs. Right?

Comment: hah you did, but I also suggest you to put some of them in the bundle so they will be shown when the user does not have a connection. :)

Comment: Did a little bit of research and it looks like admob has a feature called House ads which is not available from unity ads. I'm guessing this would mean a unity/admob integration

Comment: And it looks like there is only an open feedback vote for this: https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/house-ads

Comment: I guess you kinda answered your own question; set up a server with an interface and an endpoint which provides the ads, based on input from the interface. Then unserialize it in the game and display it. Perhaps you can achieve the same thing using [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) though.

Answer (score 1):

You technically cannot place your own *ads* on your own Games.
**A better Alternative is :**
Place Images of you other Games in the Game you want to have your ads. This is a better option as it allows you to place the `Banner Image` of your game At the *Loading Screen* or something, and it will be Free.